# Windows File Sharing not working

Tags: windows, domain, windows-firewall, share

We have a workstation on our domain that we need to share a printer from, and it's not working.  I also set up a shared folder to help with testing.

Details:

We are on a domain.  All operations performed by a domain admin account.

Group Policy has the following related set:

Policies > Windows > Security > Windows Firewall > Domain > Firewall State:  ON

Policies > Admin Template > Network > Network Connections > Windows Firewall > Domain > "Allow inbound file and printer sharing exception": Enabled, with specific ip addresses listed.

The workstations is running Windows 7.

The workstation has File & Printer Sharing Service installed.  All the required services (TCP/IP Netbios, workstation, server, ssdp, upnp, network connections, network location, computer browser) are running.

From the workstation itself, when I point Windows Explorer to its own URI (\workstation) I can see the shared printer and a shared folder.  I cannot open the shared folder, even though both its NTFS & share permissions are set to Everyone Allow All.  The error Windows Explorer gives you is: "the remote device or resource won't accept the connection."

From the domain server, which has an IP address listed to be allowed in the Group Policy above, I cannot even connect to the workstation from the Windows Explorer.  It errors out saying "Windows cannot access \workstation"

It should be noted that other machines on our network are able to have their shares viewed just fine.

Ideas welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the workstation have an administrator password setup, it must!

Answer (score 1):

Workstation rebooted and seemed to figure itself out.  It may be that, even though gpupdate/force had been run on the machine numerous times, it wasn't applying new policy as it should have been.  But it's working now.